# How do I properly pass arguments to a scriptblock using powershell runspaces?

Tags: powershell, runspace

While using runspaces I would like to pass predictable arguments to my scriptblock from outside. In order to do this without utilizing **$args** (to avoid making the code less readable), I am storing my argument in a variable called **$var** and adding the variable to the InitialSessionState of the RunspacePool. To do this I am using the `Add` method of `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.Create().Variables`

This works for my purposes, but I also noticed the `PowerShell.AddParameter` method of `[PowerShell]::Create()`which would add my parameter to each powershell process as it is created.

And finally there is the `PowerShell.AddArgument` which I could use like `AddParameter`, and use a `param()` block. this would work, however, each argument will be passed in order, and ends up working as well as **$args**.

So my question is what is the recommended way of passing arguments\parameters\variables into a scriptblock for the purposes I have defined? Is there a performance advantage of one over the other? Can you expand on what purpose you may use one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

You can use cmdlet binding inside of the script block definition.

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    Param (
        [int]$NumberofHours,
        [string]$ClientName
    )
    $LogPath = 'd:\Program Files\Exchange\Logging\RPC Client Access\*.LOG'
    $today = (Get-Date).AddHours($NumberofHours)
}
```

Then define call these parameters when you execute the script block.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList -1,$cn -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: How would this help in the instance I gave? Using powershell runspaces, I would add the Scriptblock to the powershell process using `AddScript()` Method of `PowerShell` Class, which gives me no way of passing the defined parameters without using the `AddArgument` or `AddParameter` Method's of the  `PowerShell` Class

Answer (score 2):

Here's my $.02.  I know this thread is old but I came across it unanswered while searching for something else.

This example uses a runspace pool to demonstrate how to pass parameters to the script block while using a runspace.  The function this comes from passes a datatable to a script block for processing.  Some variable names were changed to help with out-of-context readability.

```
$maxThreads = 5
$jobs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$rsp = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,$maxThreads)
$rsp.open()

$params = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]'
$params.Add('Data', $myDataTable)
$params.Add('TableName', $myTableName)

$PS = [powershell]::Create()
$PS.Runspacepool = $rsp
$PS.AddScript($myScriptBlockCode)AddParameters($parameters)
```

Another option would be to forgo the iDictionary step and simply call .AddParameter repeatedly.

```
$PS.AddScript($myScriptBlockCode).AddParame'ter(Data',$myDataTable).AddParameter('tableName',$myTableName)
```

A third way is to pass the parameters as arguments in the order they are defined in your script block

```
$PS.AddScrip(t$myScriptBlockCode).AddArgument($myDataTable).AddArgument($myTableName)
```

I hope this helps someone out.  I welcome comments as to ways to do this better.  As long as the comment doesn't suggest turning it into some amateurish one-liner that no one can read....